# Extract all four characters from a string using regular expression in R

Tags: r

I am trying to extract all four characters from a string with a pattern. It is needed to extract all seriate four characters. For example in string

```
'ghijklm'
```

the return value is a vector as follows:

```
'ghij' , 'hijk' , 'ijkl' , 'jklm'
```

Using regular expression I can extract first four string as follows:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
text1<-'ghijklm'
> text1 %>% stringr::str_match('\\w{4}')
      [,1]  
[1,] "ghij"
```

But I do not know how to continue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We may use `substring`

```
substring(text1, 1:4, 4:7)
```

-output

```
[1] "ghij" "hijk" "ijkl" "jklm"
```

---

If we want to use `str_match`, for multiple cases the suffix `_all` is needed and also, a regex lookaround will help

```
library(stringr)
str_match_all(text1, "(?=(\\w{4}))")[[1]][,2]
[1] "ghij" "hijk" "ijkl" "jklm"
```

Or

```
str_match_all(text1, "(?<=(\\w{4}))")[[1]][,2]
[1] "ghij" "hijk" "ijkl" "jklm"
```

Comment: I was not familiar with '?=' and '?!'. It is exactly I want.

Comment: @Masoud it is the [regex lookaround](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)

Answer (score 2):

Another solution, based on `purrr::map`:

```r
library(purrr)

z <- "ghijklm"
map(1:(nchar(z)-3), ~ substr(z,.x, .x+3)) %>% unlist

#> [1] "ghij" "hijk" "ijkl" "jklm"
```